# How to run git rebase and ignore whitespace?

Tags: git, git-merge

I have branch where I have one commit that only modifies whitespace (trailing whitespace and leading whitespace).

I ran `git rebase master` and `git rebase --ignore-whitespace master` and in both cases I have a merge conflict with the commit that only changed whitespace.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

I can't guarantee that this will help, but you could try
 `git rebase -Xignore-space-change master`
or
`git rebase -Xignore-all-space master`.
`-X` passes options into the merge algorithm, and the default merge algorithm has these options to affect how it handles whitespace.

Comment: but see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16598538/need-git-rebase-xignore-all-space-to-preserve-my-space

Comment: I am having trouble determining what the difference is between `-Xignore-space-change` and `-Xignore-all-space` ... seems like for most projects there are plenty of languages that are space-sensitive. It would be useful to ignore whitespace changes for only certain file extensions...

Comment: The git command fails when ran as `git rebase -Xignore-all-space --continue`.

Comment: `git pull -Xignore-all-space origin master --rebase` runs but still throws conflicts on white space diffs, presumably end of line stuff...

Answer (score 10):

This is easier with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020)

"[`git rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9c31b19dd00981fcea435de1cd05eab179039a8d/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L504)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt--i))</sup> [learns a bit more options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63751470/6309), including `--ignore-whitespace` on merge (which was not supported in 2014 when the OP used that option).

So `git rebase --ignore-whitespace master` will now work!

See [commit 6160b2e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6160b2e9a486f5dc29f621e94a0e5dcce0ab3d52) (26 Aug 2020) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
See [commit 2712669](https://github.com/git/git/commit/27126692ba1688081d8427220087bb7662594bd9) (17 Aug 2020), and [commit ef484ad](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef484add9f6ba846c62e4f13ebe0ba99b9cc4aa5) (13 Jul 2020) by [Rohit Ashiwal (`r1walz`)](https://github.com/r1walz).
See [commit a3894aa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a3894aad67df655a9c7f3b511093f681d3a01fb7), [commit 7573cec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7573cec52c0274ceb166c425be4288f6b3103d6f), [commit e8cbe21](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e8cbe2118a8e3c1aa71ed8d93f96001decebde1d) (17 Aug 2020) by [Phillip Wood (`phillipwood`)](https://github.com/phillipwood).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9c31b19](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9c31b19dd00981fcea435de1cd05eab179039a8d), 03 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`rebase -i`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ef484add9f6ba846c62e4f13ebe0ba99b9cc4aa5): add --ignore-whitespace flag
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Rohit Ashiwal</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Phillip Wood</sup>

> Rebase is implemented with two different backends - '`apply`' and '`merge`' each of which support a different set of options.
>
> In particular the `apply` backend supports a number of options implemented by '[`git am`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef484add9f6ba846c62e4f13ebe0ba99b9cc4aa5/Documentation/git-am.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-am))</sup> ' that are *not* implemented in the `merge` backend.
>
> This means that the available options are different depending on which backend is used which is confusing.
>
> This patch adds support for the `--ignore-whitespace` option to the `merge` backend.
> This option treats lines with only whitespace changes as unchanged and is implemented in the merge backend by translating it to `-Xignore-space-change`.

`git rebase` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/ef484add9f6ba846c62e4f13ebe0ba99b9cc4aa5/Documentation/git-rebase.txt#L425-L439):

> ### `--ignore-whitespace`:
>
> Ignore whitespace differences when trying to reconcile
> differences.
> Currently, each backend implements an approximation of this behavior:
>
> `apply` backend: When applying a patch, ignore changes in whitespace in context lines. Unfortunately, this means that if the "old" lines being replaced by the patch differ only in whitespace from the existing file, you will get a merge conflict instead of a successful patch application.
>
> `merge` backend: Treat lines with only whitespace changes as unchanged when merging.
> Unfortunately, this means that any patch hunks that were intended to modify whitespace and nothing else will be dropped, even if the other side had no changes that conflicted.
>
> This flag is passed to the '`git apply`' program