# Git conflict but both blocks are the same

Tags: git

I started with a `git rebase master` and after 1 skip I encountered this conflict:

`CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in web/app/components/Exchange/Exchange.jsx`
...

```
<<<<<<< HEAD

        let highestBid = bids.length > 0 ? bids.reduce((a, b) => {
            return a >= b.price_full ? a : b.price_full;
        }, 0) : 0;

=======

        let highestBid = bids.length > 0 ? bids.reduce((a, b) => {
            return a >= b.price_full ? a : b.price_full;
        }, 0) : 0;

>>>>>>> Minor exchange fixes, ...
```

The looked the same but since I have seen this before I double-checked the code manually.  Both blocks are the same hash after I copy and pasted them to two files..

Any idea on what has happened and how to automatically resolve conflicts like this?

`git version 1.9.1`

Comment: Did these identical lines of code come from 2 different commits?

Comment: you should check whitespaces in the conflicting parts.

Comment: Don't forget about specific whitespace - end-of-line symbols.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to quickly check if this is about space issue, [you can try (as I mentioned before)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13415932/6309):

```
 git rebase --abort # provided you didn't already resolved a ton of other conflicts before
 git rebase -Xignore-space-change master
 # or
 git rebase -Xignore-all-space master
```

Note that that would *not* keep your [whitespace changes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16598538/6309) (since [rebase invert ours and theirs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3052118/6309))